# Browser Request Slow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have an ASP.net\AJAX 4.0 forms application that is having a performance issue. The app is hosted on go daddy shared hosting servers. Intermittently (about half the time) a page request hangs for a significant amount of time. I have run lots of tracing on it and found that the hangup is happening before the request even gets to the server. I have setup ASP.net tracing to spit out a timestamp gathered during the application.begin_request event. An example of a typical scenario I am observing is that I request a page at 00 seconds and get the response at 30 seconds. ASP.net tracing tells me that application.begin_request (via the timestamp) started at 27 seconds and the entire page cycle took less than 3 seconds to complete.

I also traced with the Internet Explorer 9 F12 debug feature and if I look at the timings tab (in detail view) I observe that all of the hangup time is occuring in what Internet Explorer is calling the "Start" event - the description is "The time from when the request was initially created to when the request is sent".

So my question is, does anybody know what would cause requests to intermittently get held up in the browser like that? It does not happen in development (only from hosted site) and occurs from multiple types of browsers and multiple PCs - so it is not isolated to a particular browser environment.

Comment: Sounds like a problem at GoDaddy's end. Try a different hosting provider (Windows Azure is free for three months).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your trace is accurate then it's a tossup - although based (only) on what you posted, it seems like a networking matter. Before pointing fingers, do due diligence - e.g. `trace route` (test for latency on each "hop"), `nslookup` (test for DNS resolution), and the "obvious" - e.g. your own networking environment - are you on WLAN when testing? These are all "possibles" for *intermittent* issues.

Comment: I have done some DNS resolution testing and other network tracing and haven't found an issue. Testing has happened from many networks. From home over broadband connections, also from LAN office environments. Always the results are the same. Very cruddy peformance. I have run the IE tracing from both home and office\LAN and observer the same thing where it sticks in the "Start" state for a long time.

Comment: I guess I need to test on a different hosting provider and see if results are different. I just wish I could figure out what is going on during that "start" state it is taking so long in.

Comment: @user1672453 see if [this GoDaddy announcement](http://support.godaddy.com/godaddy/ceo-addresses-sept-10-service-outage/) has anything to do with your woes....

Comment: The service outage discussed in the announcement you linked to was limited to September 10, 2012.  It would not still be causing intermittent issues now.

Comment: I am aware of the service outage but this has been going on since before that and also after. I just ran tracing using dynaTrace and it tells me that the site is very responsive in all ways accept for overall load time on those occassions when the random holdup occurs. It shows the lag time occurring in what it calls the upfront "Wait" time. Typically this "Wait" time is 0 seconds on page requests that experience no holdup.

Comment: Can you share the URL for the page that is having the issue so we can see exactly what you are talking about?

Comment: Go daddy support again basically told me to pound sand. Talked to a live person that checked with advanced hosting support. The answer that came back was the server is setup fine and it is probably the Webresource.axd script that is running on the login page. That is an ASP.net generated script. Not sure how that would cause intermittent slowness. Anyways, I will be testing on a different hosting provider soon.

Comment: So I finally found a couple cases where others have experienced the same issue. I did some testing using Fiddler. It appears I have the same issue that was present in both of these cases:

Comment: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/28020-Website-suddenly-running-slow

Comment: I have passed the info on to Go Daddy hosting support. Will see what happens.